# wordpress 4.22 does not generate thumbnail images

Tags: images

I had problem I uploaded images and wordpress did not auto generate any thumbnails,
My server is ubuntu 14.04 wordpress is running on apache2
I downloaded some plugins that were supposed to force generate the thumbnails but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing on the server php5-gd

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Comment: this was the issue on my site, shouldn't wordpress show an error message ?

Comment: it should show some information/log but I don't remember that I saw any error messages it could save my time and I guess yours as well.. :)